# Where are Block and Lot fields in Esri Local Government Information Model Geodatabase Schema?

Tags: esri-geodatabase, parcel, arcgis-local-government

I am looking at the ESRI [Local Government Information Model (LGIM) geodatabase schema](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=5f799e6d23d94e25b5aaaf2a58e63fb1) and I cannot find the Feature Class that holds the parcels' Block and Lot information.

Do you know which Feature Class in LGIM schema holds the Block&Lot information?

Under the "ParcelPublishing" dataset there is a "Block" polygon feature class, but I don't see Block and Lot fields in it.

Comment: Under the "ParcelPublishing" dataset there is a "Block" polygon feature class, but I don't see Block and Lot fields in it

Answer (score 1):

In the ParcelEditing feature dataset, under ParcelFabric, ParcelFabric_Parcels contains a field called 'BlockDesignator' which has an alias of 'Block Number'.